# Что означает  ++$this->position?

Tags: php

```
сlass myIterator implements Iterator {
    private $position = 0;
    private $array = array(
        "firstelement",
        "secondelement",
        "lastelement"
    );

    public function __construct() {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    function next() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        ++$this->position;
    }

}

$it = new myIterator;
```

Никак не пойму что за конструкция ++$this->position;

Comment: ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/ceREP.png

Comment: Только непонятно зачем с этом случае ++$a, а не более привычный $a++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это означает, что инкрементируеся свойство `position`, т.е. переход к следующему элементу.  Более понятная форма записи выглядит так:

```
++($this->position);
```

или даже так:

```
++$position;
```

Comment: а чем уже не нравивиться запись  $this->++position?

Comment: Ясность кода - это одно из главных его качеств. Запись `++$position` - проще некуда, а значит, она и лучше.

Comment: спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 2):

Данная операция увеличивает операнд на 1. В данном случае переменная position вашего класса увеличивается на единицу. Операция называется Префиксный инкремент, почитать о ней можее здесь:

[Операторы инкремента и декремента в PHP](http://www.php.su/learnphp/operators/?id).